# LDAPS certificate in Microsoft AD

Tags: python, ldap

How can we pass security key instead of file during authentication?

For file it's working for me, but I have challenge to pass security key. Is it possible?

Code for certificate file:

```
l = ldap.initialize('ldaps://localhost636')
print(ldap.get_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE))
# ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, 'C:\\Users\\DE00030688\\Desktop\\MicrosoftLDAPS\\LDAPSEC2.cer')
username = "localhost@test.com"
password = "Qwer1234$!"
try:
    l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
    l.simple_bind_s(username, password)
except Exception as e:
    print("******Exception in LDAP Connection******** " + e)
return l
```